# To run unit test cases using rest assured framework in adobe cq6 insatance

Tags: java, unit-testing

```
@Test
public void testExecute() throws Exception {
        Response res = get("http://localhost:4502/payback/cr.json/getPersonPath");
        assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
}
```

I have added dependencies to classpath, but still while running test cases i am getting the following exception, why?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
```

Comment: Is this some jee ? (I see some "apache" in error log)  Are you using spring or maybe some maven ? Are you working on eclipse ? Have you tried running an empty test ? (just assertTrue(true); )

Comment: where have you put your test class???? and please can you attach the dependencies?

Comment: @Asoub, running an empty test (asserTrue(true);) working fine, I am working on  intelliJ Idea

Comment: @SandraSukarieh, My test class is placed under class(same package), dependencies are junit 4.11, rest-assured 1.4, hamcrest-all 1.3 version

Comment: I suppose you're using logger in your get method ?  Cleaning the projet may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to add groovey-all dependency cause sometimes there are issues with spring, you may add it like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
<artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
<version>the same version as REST</version>
</dependency>
```

Second, from run configurations where you added your test, make sure it can find your test class and your test method (they appear in red if it can't find them), so in this case try to edit the location.

Comment: Thank you, i placed test classes under src-->test folder, its working fine, before it was in main-->java